# How to select a specific element from a list of rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following series (df):

```
Index    Information
1        [2, A, C]
2        [3, B, C]
3        [4, C, H]
4        [5, D, H]
5        [6, E, H]
6        [7, F, H]
```

and I want a series that only extracts and stores the third value of each list :

```
Index    Information
1        [C]
2        [C]
3        [H]
4        [H]
5        [H]
6        [H]
```

If I try 
`df[0][2]`, it correctly gives the required output `[C]`.

however, if I try `df[:][2]`, instead of giving

```
[C]
[C]
[H]
[H]
[H]
[H]
```

the output is

```
3        [4, C, H]
```

What should be the correct syntax for this?

Comment: how are you creating the dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `pandas.Series.str`

```
df.Information.str[2:3]

0    [C]
1    [C]
2    [H]
3    [H]
4    [H]
5    [H]
Name: Information, dtype: object
```

### With `assign`

```
df.assign(Information=df.Information.str[2:3])

   Index Information
0      1         [C]
1      2         [C]
2      3         [H]
3      4         [H]
4      5         [H]
5      6         [H]
```

---

### comprehension per [@coldspeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453574/how-to-select-a-specific-element-from-a-list-of-rows-in-python/50453636?noredirect=1#comment87921660_50453636)

```
df.assign(Information=[l[2:3] for l in df.Information.tolist()])

   Index Information
0      1         [C]
1      2         [C]
2      3         [H]
3      4         [H]
4      5         [H]
5      6         [H]
```

Comment: You may go for the alternative `[l[2:3] for l in df.Information.tolist()]` as well.

Comment: what if the name of the column labelled 'information' is a varies depending on size of the data? How can I represent it?

Comment: @KrishnaAnapindi In that case `[l[-1:] for l in df.Information.tolist()]` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
df["new_col"] = df["Information"].apply(lambda x: x[2])
```